# Questions about JNI on Android

Tags: java, android, c++, linux, java-native-interface

I am planning to create a software that will be compatible with both Windows CE and Android devices.

Nothing has been decided yet, but so far I've imagined that I could write most parts of the program using C++ code that could be reused on these two platforms, except for system-dependant things like threads. C++ is highly recommended for performance in my case.

In the case of system-dependent things I would create interfaces that would be implemented in two different ways, one using the win32 API, and the other one using the linux equivalent. The other parts of the code the logic) would be independent and reused on both platforms.

The only part of the application that would not be written in C++ would be the user interface. Using the Android API on Android platforms, and something else on Windows CE (C#, Java, don't know yet).

I've read that Android is not like other linux distributions because many linux features are not available from native code on it.

**So my question is : is it possible to natively create and use sockets, threads, critical sections (and any other system-dependant things) from a native linux api using JNI (i.e the equivalent of the win32 api but for linux) or do i always have to create them into the Java layer and pass them down to the native code ?**

I've not yet decided how II am going to build this, i'm just informing myself on the different possibilities.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

NDK implemented POSIX (include pthread, mutex) and BSD socket, so you don't necessary create them with java objects.

However, STL support is still crappy IMO, which you may need to pay attention with your own code or porting any dependency libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do all of this with JNI, but I would think twice before doing so. Using JNI has its share of liabilities; it will make development and debugging **considerably** more difficult. You will also end up with a lot of callbacks to Java code to communicate with the GUI. Think of features like visual progress indicators for ongoing operations. And don't forget that in the end, your app's performance may *suffer* because of the extra indirection required by each JNI call. Be sure to measure performance in either case. **JNI, or C++ for that matter, does not automatically make anything faster.**

Also, it may be harder than what you think to just "mirror" your app on another operating system. Android, as an operating system, behaves differently not only on the GUI side (it is, for example, nonsense to provide a back button within in an Android app), but also on the inside, with its typical app architecture broken down into Services, Activities and Receivers. It's not just "a different GUI", not at all.

If you have backend functionality that really can and should behave identically on both platforms, then go on, write it in C++ and reuse it on Android via JNI. But it *may* be easier, and it *may* be equally or more performant, to just implement it or parts of it from scratch on Android, using Java. Without knowing any details about your project, it is impossible to say.

Why don't you try and implement a simple test app on Android using JNI? Try to use the NDK to send an HTTP request in a background thread and write the respone back to Java as a `String`. You'll eventually see that it works, but you will also have a better understanding of the difficulties involved.